# django : How to change or decoding admin page's currently box path string

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, admin

I'm now using model's filefield as django's rest framework.

I want to decode or control the 'Currently' box url path shown in the admin page.

[image]

**models.py**

```
class PdfuploadfileMange(models.Model):
      pdffile =models.FileField(upload_to=path_upload_to,storage=CustomFileSystemStorage())
```

**serializer.py**

```
class pdffileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
            model = PdfuploadfileMange
            fields = ['id',pdffile']
```

**views.py**

```
class FileUploadview(APIView):
      def post(self,request,format=None):
          .....
          serializer = pdffileSerializer()
          .....
```

Comment: What do you mean _decode or control_? That's the relative file path to your file.

Comment: For example, I want to decode this encoded path aaa/bbb/%2f%22% 3f.pdf on screen.  currnetly : not show aaa/bbb/%2f%22% 3f.pdf  -> It's  aaa/bbb/"?.pdf